# How to diagnose thermistor problem

Tags: thermistor, fault

I have a thermistor which I believe is a NTC 3950, and which I suspect does not work properly.

It is from a 3D printer extruder/hot end. The displayed temperatures and the ones I measure using a meat thermometer differ by 50% or more, and I can feel with my hand in the vicinity (not touching) that it is cooler than it used to be.

The normal operating temperature is around 200 deg C. The resistance of the thermistor at room temperature, measured by a multimeter, is 108k Ohm, which seems to be normal.

Any other things I can do to test the thermistor before replacing it? I do not have an electronics lab, only basic stuff. Can it even be the thermistor that causes the problem, ie is it normal/not unheard of for a thermistor to give normal values at room temperature and be off by 50% at higher temperatures?

Comment: First, I think you need a better reference than a meat thermometer.

Comment: @Barry I don't think the exact number of degrees is super important. There is an obvious difference from the way it was before.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the thermistor is a good place to start. Replace it and see if that works. That’s the simple solution.

If you want to further test the thermistor, use a multimeter to to measure the resistance while wiggling the thermistor to test for breaks in the wires.

If you have the spec sheet on the thermistor, you can measure the resistance of the thermistor and see if it matches the spec sheet. Use ice water as a reference if necessary.

Just replacing it is probably the simplest though. You should keep extra thermistors on hand anyway for when it does go out.

Comment: It's just odd that everything looks ok in the software. It shows 25 deg initially (true value 21-22, ie room temperature), and then when I set it to 200 (and the termistor value goes up to that), the meat thermometer shows around 130 eventually. If the termistor had been broken it should show negative values, or some error msg. If I disconnect the termistor I get an error indication in the sw.

Comment: Anything is possible. Stuff fails all kinds of different ways. That’s why, for cheap components, it’s usually easiest to just replace it and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Okay, that's one way to look at it.

Comment: It probably isn’t software unless you were fiddling around with the code. So it is probably hardware. Well, which components are most vulnerable?  The PCB is usually enclosed and protected. So most likely your issue is the thermistor itself or the cable running to it.

Comment: I did not say the sw was the problem, I said the sw does not display thermistor error indications. Part of the issue is that I have already replaced the termistor, but not with an identical one (they may in fact be the same type, I am not sure), and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: I didn’t mean to suggest that you thought the software was the problem. I was thinking of all the possible elements that could cause the problem, software being one of them. Putting in the wrong thermistor would absolutely explain the behavior you explained. Especially because the temperature is slightly off near room temp and way off at an extreme temperature. However, I assume it was working and then switched to the odd behavior with the same thermistor, so I have no idea.